# Python Multiple LDAP3 Authentication

Tags: python, django, ldap3

I have two questions...the first is I can authenticate using the below with my email address but I cannot with my AD Username.  I have changed "username": "mail" --> "username": "sAMAccountName" didn't work...also tried "uid" nothing doing...so what's the deal?

```
LDAP_AUTH_URL = "ldap://some_address"
LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_USERNAME = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_username_active_directory"
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "dc=various_dc_values,dc=com"
LDAP_AUTH_OBJECT_CLASS = 'Person'

LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = {
 "username": "mail",
 "first_name": "givenName",
 "last_name": "sn",
 "email": "mail",
```

}

Second question is that I want to authenticate on multiple domains so as I couldn't work out how to add the other domain into the settings file I added my own function.

```
#Authenticate User using backend
#User object is returned with forename and surname.  Referenced in Templates.
user = auth.authenticate(username=email, password=password)

#did it work or is this a user that belongs to a different domain?
if user is None:
     #Create new User object.  This line doesn't work as expected, I want a blank authenticated User object not whatever this creates
     user = django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)

     #Authenticate User with different domain
     #Request comes back with forename and surname set
     TryOtherAuthentication( email, password, request)

     #Code breaks here - 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'first_name'
     user.first_name = request.user.first_name
     user.last_name = request.user.last_name
     user.is_staff = request.user.is_staff
     user.save()
```

So the question I guess is how do I create a User object like the one that is returned using backend authentication?

If the User object is authenticated using backend authenticated then this code works.

```
user.first_name = 'Bugsy'
user.last_name = 'Malone'
user.save()
```

I know that my function to authenticate with other server works and that the values are returned in request.

I just cannot workout how to create a Userobject so that the user is directed to the Index page.

```
if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect('index')
```

Answer (score 0):

LDAP3 doesn't currently support mutliple backend authentication it seems.

So I basically just had to ignore the whole 'user' and simply have session variables to hold the values.  Thankfully the app wasn't very big so didn't need many alterations.